# How to route PHP files to 2 different backends with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a server running Nginx that is currently proxying all PHP script to Apache with the following location directive:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass http://@apache;
}
```

I'd like to introduce a new location directive like:

```
location ~* ^/blog/(.*\.php)$ {
    alias /opt/blog/public;
    fastcgi_pass  @phpfpm;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

But when I access http://example.com/blog/test.php I'm hitting Apache and not php-fpm. How can I make the new location directive take precedence over the Apache location?

Comment: try switching `location` places?